# Java: How to read values from .txt file

Tags: java, file, loops, average

I'm writing a program that uses 30 grades from a file and calculates the lowest, highest, and average grades. I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the loop statement that reads each grade and updates the lowest/highest grade and adds that value to the sum before reading the next grade.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MidtermStat {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("grades.txt"));
        int lowest = 50;
        int highest = 50;
        int sum = 0;

        int i;
        for (i = 0, i < 30, i++){
            if (grade < lowest)
                lowest = grade;
            if (grade > highest)
                highest = grade;
        }

        double average = sum / 30;

        System.out.println("The average score is: " + average);
        System.out.println("The highest score is: " + highest);
        System.out.println("The lowest score is: " + lowest);

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks figured it out:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MidtermStat {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("grades.txt"));
        int lowest = 50;
        int highest = 50;
        int sum = 0;

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
            int grade = in.nextInt();
            if (grade < lowest)
                lowest = grade;
            if (grade > highest)
                highest = grade;
            sum += grade;
        }

        double average = (sum / 30.0);

        System.out.println("The average score is: " + (int)(average * 100) / 100.0);
        System.out.println("The highest score is: " + highest);
        System.out.println("The lowest score is: " + lowest);

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This `sum / 30` is integer division.

Comment: Typecast that to double average = (double)sum / 30;

Comment: You need to read something from the file and update the values from within the loop...

Comment: in... don't forget to use the in...

Comment: should be `(sum / 30.0)` to get the correct floating point average

Comment: How do I read from the file to access the grade and update the lowest/highest/sum?

Comment: What does your file look like? Is it comma separated?

Comment: Are they separated by some spaces?

Comment: The grades in the file are a value between 0 and 100. The grades are saved as one grade per line.

Comment: OT: You should initialize your high and low with the max/minimum of your grades. Because when all grades are under 50 your maximum is anyway 50. Or better us the "Integer.MIN_VALUE" and "Integer.MAX_VALUE" for initalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
 for(i=0;i<30;i++){
       **float grade = in.nextFloat();**
       if(grade<lowest) lowest = grade;
       else if(grade>highest) highest = grade;

       sum+=grade;

    }
```

Dont forget to change every "int" you have used to "float" for precision.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for buffered reader.

For eg

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FilePath"))
```

the above statement will give you exception and you need to handle it.

```
while ((Line = br.readLine()) != null) {
// your statements..
}
```

Happy coding

Comment: Why can't he continue using the Scanner that he's already created, an object that more easily read in numbers? Why are you recommending that he change to a BufferedReader?

Comment: ya I forgot to mention.. 

you are not taking care of your sum and moreover.


In this scenario we can consider each score is given line by line.

eg 
71
62
63 and so on...

Comment: I haven't learned this method yet. We just finished going over loops and this method of accessing a file with different values was never explained.

Answer (score 0):

Use This if your file contains floats value

while (b = in.hasNextFloat())

```
    {
        s = s1.nextFloat();
        sum += s;
    }
```

Please keep in mind that if you are taking input from the file then it is better to use BufferdReader as the file is saved in disk which is slow as compare to our program. So it is better to use some low level stream while reading from a file.
for more details you can refer :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html